# TypeScript implementing interface in class

Tags: typescript

I am new in TypeScript, could anyone help me to figure it out the best practices with implementing interface in class? Because when I tried to following the Docs ([Class Heritage](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#class-heritage)), I caught in some problem like so:

1. declare interface

```js
interface Notification {
    message: string;
    send(msg?: string): void;
}
```

2. implements interface in class with `constructor()`

```js
class Notifier implements Notification {
    constructor(
        public message: string,
    ){}

    send(customMsg?: string): void {
        if (customMsg) {
            console.log(customMsg);
        } else {
            console.log(this.message);
        }
    }
}
```

3. example, using class

```js
const hello = new Notifier("hello");
hello.send();
hello.send("Alert!");
```

Unfortunately, I found an error message like the following:

> Class 'Notifier' incorrectly implements interface 'Notification'.
> Type 'Notifier' is missing the following properties from type 'Notification': actions, badge, body, data, and 19 more.

Could anyone tell me what is my wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Aside: I am changing your `message` property from `private` to `public` or you will hit a new error after you resolve the current one.  Since you are not asking about `private` vs `public`, this issue is therefore outside the scope of the question and we should clear things up by using `public`, as my answer below does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that [the TypeScript standard library already includes a globally-scoped `interface` named `Notification`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/38da7c600c83e7b31193a62495239a0fe478cb67/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts#L2367) corresponding to the [`Notification` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) from the [Web Workers API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API).  Because of this, your `Notification` `interface` definition is just [merging additional members into it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces).  This is obviously not what you intend.

The fix here is either to rename your `interface` to something else like `MyNotification`, or create a `module` or `namespace` that creates a new naming scope for your code:

```
// use of "export" makes your code a module
export interface Notification { 
    message: string;
    send(msg?: string): void;
}
```

or

```
namespace MyNamespace {
  export interface Notification {
    message: string;
    send(msg?: string): void;
  }
}
```

And then you should be able to refer to it later.  If you use the `namespace` approach, you'll get this:

```
class Notifier implements MyNamespace.Notification {
  constructor(
    public message: string, 
  ) { }

  send(customMsg?: string): void {
    if (customMsg) {
      console.log(customMsg);
    } else {
      console.log(this.message);
    }
  }
}


const hello = new Notifier("hello");
hello.send();
hello.send("Alert!");
```

Which works as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBZAngOXNOikG8BYAKCSQgA8YB7AJwBckBLYeiWgMwWQ2vqY5N4IftWAESZMpChQQAcwgAuJFHq0W8gNySpUCMAAmACjBR5AfhVqNweQEoVAN2pNDO0kgC+JH8RLwADYgski8-ILszGAwgRCQrFComNiw3AB04QJCIkxiEp7wYjYArvD0dMa6ZDAlAEaBQkgycorW6poANEgA9D1IwsAA5Ix1yDAaTiIQ3VB0tGi69gTeJLr6RsbwJWrUYCjmVqoddo5ILm4FUswcSFs7Ffvmy0Se10XAc3HpgdTy97sng4PNcvORAvortcBsVqN9fv96AALJhQdItBQQewgqR+Mh+PxrYgfNRIJEQQK-JAAXiQwAgAHcwnxsuxjAAicmU6js7EkLm-dIbEx84gC6hCgwmdkAQTiDAAhLyPEA)

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't realize it and it is work when I change the name of that interface to `MyNotification`.

Comment: But, how about using private access modifiers in constructor while implementing an interface? Since in your example, we must change `message` property to public.

Comment: That's a different question, isn't it?  If I have a `MyNotification` object, I should be allowed to access its `message` property, according to your interface definition.  If `Notifier` makes `message` a `private` property, then I can't do that.  Just like you couldn't make it a `number` if it is supposed to be a `string`.  Therefore, making it `private` causes `Notifier` not to be a valid `MyNotification`.  You can have private properties in `Notifier`, but they cannot conflict with properties from `MyNotification`.

Comment: A comment section is not a good place to discuss this subsequent issue.  You should consider doing more research to look for existing questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37791947/how-to-define-a-private-property-when-implementing-an-interface-in-typescript), and if you can't find an answer, consider posting a new question. Good luck!